# For loop in R to search through column names

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for helping out with this.

I have a dataframe in R that has a Year column (year = 2008-2017) for individual rows, and individual columns with headings like this (Price_2008, Cause_2008, Price_2009, Cause_2009, etc).

The idea is to create another 2 columns in the dataframe with heading Price and Cause, and by looking at the Year to point to the right column to get the data. (i.e: if year = 2018, choose Price_2018 and Cause_2018).

Any ideas to do this is appreciated! I am very new with R and cannot do this in SAS...

Thanks!

Added Code:

```
for (i in c(2008:2017)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(abc)){
   if (abc$year[j] == i) {(abc$Price[j]<-c(abc$Price_2008:abc$Price_2017)[j]) 
   & (abc$Cause[j]<-c(abc$Cause_2008:abc$Cause_2017)[j])
 }}}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please show us your efforts first.

Comment: I think this question can be OK if you enhance it a little bit more providing some sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to get the price and cause value and apply that per row. E.g.

```
year <- ceiling(runif(10,2007,2010))
price_2008 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
price_2009 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
price_2010 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
price_2011 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
cause_2008 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
cause_2009 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
cause_2010 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
cause_2011 <- rnorm(10,10,3)
df <- data.frame(year, price_2008, price_2009, price_2010, price_2011, cause_2008, cause_2009, cause_2010, cause_2011)
getPriceValue <- function(x){
   columnPrice <- 1 + 2011 - x[1]
   return(x[columnPrice])
}
getCauseValue <- function(x){
  columnPrice <- 5 + 2011 - x[1]
  return(x[columnPrice])
}
df$price <- apply(df,1,getPriceValue)
df$cause <- apply(df, 1, getCauseValue)
df
```

Comment: `year <- sample(2007:2010, 10, repl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer [`dplyr`](https://www.tidyverse.org)-based solution

## Data

```
set.seed(123)
year <- ceiling(runif(10, 2007, 2010))
price_2008 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
price_2009 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
price_2010 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
price_2011 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
cause_2008 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
cause_2009 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
cause_2010 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
cause_2011 <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)
df <-
    data.frame(
        year,
        price_2008,
        price_2009,
        price_2010,
        price_2011,
        cause_2008,
        cause_2009,
        cause_2010,
        cause_2011
    )
```

## Solution

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(key = "cause", value = "value", -year) %>%
    separate(col = "cause",
             into = c("type", "type_year"),
             sep = "_") %>% 
    filter(type_year == year) -> dta_res
```

### Results

```
# head(dta_res)
  year  type type_year     value
1 2008 price      2008 15.145195
2 2008 price      2008 13.672245
3 2009 price      2009  4.100149
4 2009 price      2009  9.346075
5 2009 price      2009  7.813326
6 2009 price      2009  8.124882
```

## Notes

- I reckon it's easy to read and leaves you scope to expand the
  filters, whether you want to match years, filter for `cause` only or
  filter for values and so on.
- I've left `type_year` and `type` columns but you can remove those passing `select()` call to your `dplyr` pipeline or using `remove` argument`in`seprate` call if you prefer.